# error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++, oop

whats the problem of this code that i take the above error?

TIA

```
#include"PositionInfo.h"

bool DecisionTree::Decision(Agent & agent) {

PositionInfo Player_position;
double metr=Player_position.GetBallDistToTeammate(5);

if (agent.GetSelf().IsKickable()) {

Kicker::instance().KickBall(agent,agent.GetWorldState().GetTeammate(5).GetPos(),metr);

}
}
```

i changed the code now i got this error:

error: no matching function for call to ‘PositionInfo::PositionInfo()’

Edited:

according to  johnsyweb response:

in class PositionInfo we have like this:

```
    PositionInfo(WorldState *pWorldState, InfoState *pInfoState);
```

and i put it like this in DecisionTree:

```
    PositionInfo Player_position(WorldState *pWorldState, InfoState *pInfoState);

   double met=Player_position//but here IDE doesnt let me to put GetBallDistToTeammate()
```

Comment: You'll need to *read the code* in `"PositionInfo.h"` to find out what the arguments to `PositionInfo`'s constructor are and provide those, as per my answer.

Comment: `PositionInfo Player_position(WorldState *pWorldState, InfoState *pInfoState);` is not correct syntax. You'll need to pass in pointers to valid objects here (assuming that `PositionInfo Player_position(NULL, NULL);` will yield nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PositionInfo` is a class. `GetBallDistToTeammate()` is a method.

Given the name of the function and the number of arguments (one), I would suggest that a `static` method would not be be able to calculate a distance with that information.

As such you'd need to construct an instance of `PositionInfo` (let's call it `player_position`) probably as a member of your `DecisionTree` and presumably call some other method upon it to set its position (from your edit, its position is set in the *constructor* `PositionInfo::PositionInfo()`, which takes *at least* one argument).

Then in `DecisionTree::Decision()` you could call `player_position.GetBallDistToTeammate(5)` and get a number of metres back.

Comment: thanks but i didnt understand what you mean in this sentence:call some other method upon it to set its position.i edited my question,plz see is it correct or missing sth else

Comment: @arash: I've updated my answer accordingly. You need to find out what the arguments to `PositionInfo::PositionInfo()` are and construct `PositionInfo Player_position(` *<correct arguments here>* `)`.

Comment: Well now you need pointers to `WorldState` and `InfoState` objects. Presumably you'll need to create these yourself before pass them into the constructor. I am sorry, I cannot write this code for you.

Answer (score 4):

A class name is not a primary expression. You should either create an object of type `PositionInfo` and use that to call `GetBallDistToTeammate` or use `PositionInfo::`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because it should be `PositionInfo::GetBallDistToTeammate(5)`?  I assume this is a static function.  `.` is used in Java/C# and `::` in C++ to access static members.

In response to your editing question

It looks like `PositionInfo::GetBallDistToTeamMate` is not a static member function.  You will need an instance of position info (e.g. a variable of that type) to call the method on.  It doesn't look like you have one in the function, so maybe there is one as a member of `DecisionTree`?  It's difficult to tell without more information.